fill values of a Push button from a file
In a beamer, I want to have a button which will gave a random value of a list when clicked upon.
Here's an example of a start

\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{ocgx2}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}

\noindent
\PushButton[name=randomButton, onclick={
    var values = ["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"];
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length);
    this.getField("randomText").value = values[randomIndex];
}]{Click here}\\[1ex]

\TextField[name=randomText, width=10cm, height=1cm]{}

\end{Form}

\end{document}

I would like to have the values ["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"] in an external file (a line per value). How can I modify this code to do so?
Thanks!

Welcome! Are you aware that most PDF viewers will not support this? (Not necessarily a reason not to do it, just sometimes people don't realise how viewer dependent something like this is going to be.)

@cfr That's not really an issue for me as I don't plan to distribute the file, but  rather project it from my computer.

\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{ocgx2}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite,noheader]{jsvalues.txt}
"Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"
\end{filecontents}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\file_get:nnN {jsvalues.txt} {}\myjsvalues
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\begin{Form}

\noindent
\PushButton[name=randomButton, onclick={
    var values = [\myjsvalues];
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length);
    this.getField("randomText").value = values[randomIndex];
}]{Click here}\\[1ex]

\TextField[name=randomText, width=10cm, height=1cm]{}

\end{Form}

\end{document}

